# Sending data in 'Request Payload' using amplifyjs

Tags: amplifyjs

I have a javascript object to be sent to server as follow :

```
var input = {a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: 'ccc'};
```

And I want to send **'a'** property in url like this

```
http://localhost/rest/customer/aaa
```

That's fine with url substitution feature in amplifyjs as follow :

```
amplify.request.define('update-customer', 'ajax', {
    url : 'rest/customer/{a}',
    dataType: 'json',
    type : 'PUT'
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8;
});

amplify.request('update-customer', { a : input.a, data : input });
```

The point I am struggling with is that I would like to send b and c property as a form data in json format as a 'Request Payload', however it is failed becauseof the form data is sent as follow :

```
Request Payload :
  data : {b : 'bbb', c : 'ccc'}
```

So what I want to achieve is to remove **'data'** key in 'Request Payload' as follow :

```
Request Payload :
 {b : 'bbb', c : 'ccc'}
```

I tested this in REST Client program and was successed.

To wrap up my question, How to send data attached in Request Body without key name using **amplifyjs**?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
amplify.request.define('update-customer', 'ajax', {
  url: 'rest/customer/{a},
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: {
    b : '{b}',
    c : '{c}'
  }
});

amplify.request('update-customer', { a : input.a, data : input });
```

This solution has a problem if input.b or input.c are null. [Check this post for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978690/how-to-build-request-with-optional-data-using-amplifyjs)