# How to build request with optional data using AmplifyJS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, amplifyjs

I have a RESTful web service with this format:

```
/users?age={age}
```

As it is defined, the web service works whether I add age parameter or not. So both examples are correct:

```
/users
```

or

```
/users?age=18
```

The amplify's request definition:

```
amplify.request.define( "usersService", "ajax", {
  url: "/users",
  type: "GET",
  data: {age : "{age}"}
});
```

Invocation that works:

```
var myAge = 18;
amplify.request("usersService", {age : myAge});
```

Result is:

```
GET /users?age=18 
Response code: 200 OK
```

Invocation that does not work:

```
var myAge = null;
amplify.request("usersService", {age : myAge});
```

Result is:

```
GET /users?age=
Response code: 400 BAD REQUEST
```

The correct result I was expecting when age is not defined is:

```
GET/users
Response code: 200 OK
```

Any idea how to make this example works?

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Neuquino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not to define the "data" in request.define and adding or not the age attribute to the invocation.

```
var input = null;
if(myAge != null){
  input.age = myAge
}
amplify.request("usersService",input);


amplify.request.define( "usersService", "ajax", {
  url: "/users",
  type: "GET",    
});
```

input is merged in the body, so if is empty, nothing is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

amplify.request("usersService", {});

amplify.request("usersService");